# Is it appropriate to leave office after working hours, even if being forced to stay to finish tasks?

Tags: management, work-time, overtime

So I have been working in this company for an year now and the only problem I am facing since then is that I am forced to stay in office even my working hours are completed.

We are not paid overtime here. 10 A.M to 7.30 P.M is our working time, means 9 hours 30 minutes. We have already discussed that this timing is too much for a Software Engineer but they didn't take any action.

Currently, I am the only resource they have for projects so I am forced to stay and complete the tasks. They burden me with tasks and when it is time to leave they ask me to stay as tasks are not being completed. It is okay for me to survive this once, twice or thrice a month but this happens on regular basis. I always feel fed up as I have some other hobbies, interests or tasks to complete as a Freelancer too.

How should I tackle such boss? Isn't it my right to ask them that I can't stay more as I have other activities to do?

Comment: Looks like you need to look for a new job.  A "normal" working time of 9 hours and 30 minutes isn't normal, and forcing you to work extra unpaid is just insane.

Comment: If you are salaried (not paid by the hour), then in general you have the choice to work longer or refuse, and they have the option of accepting your decision to limit work hours or firing you. In the US, there is very little recourse for salaried employees when work hours are long, other than to leave. Other countries have more rules about work hours, but in the US it is not at all uncommon for some employers to work their staff almost exactly the 37.5 hours a week that are normal working hours - and in others if you don't work 80 hours you are out.

Comment: I too would brush off my resume and start looking elsewhere.

Comment: This almost feels like a good reason to go home sick right after your time is up.  You can't work overtime because your sick.  Job done.  Typically employers can't ask you what your sick with.  And because your not missing any regular hours, they can't really force you to bring a doctors note.  They can terminate your contract, but then you will probably get severance (check your employment contract)

Comment: "They didn't take any action" is too passive. Take action yourself. Tell them you will no longer be working so many hours. Then they can either accept it or fire you.

Comment: Can you add a tag with your location? That will help people provide relevant answers. Most people here default to US-based answers, but in other areas, there may be laws or regulations regarding your question.

Comment: What are they doing to "force" this on you? Are they asking nicely? Or threatening you? Or locking you in the building? It's hard to suggest a response without knowing the intensity/severity of their actions (ie if they're asking nicely, you might try to respond with a conversion. But if they're threatening or taking some physical action to stop you from leaving, that's a very different matter).

Comment: @dwizum they always play safe, they never threatened me but the way they ask me to stay is just like 'A joker in a horror movie asking a young boy to come have this candy', LOL

Comment: What's driving the need to complete tasks - an internal deadline, or an external deadline? Or just that they don't think they're seeing enough progress from you? Who sets the priorities and estimates that you work to - do you have a project manager, or is that all on you too?

Comment: In the US and you're an exempt employee (you are salaried and you don't get overtime), you can be asked to work >40 hour weeks without pay.

Comment: You are expected to work between 10 AM and 7:30 PM.  How long do they give you for lunch?  One would typically expect at least an hour for lunch which is paid.

Comment: `the only problem I am facing since then is that I am forced to stay in office even my working hours are completed.` - Unless you're an indentured servant they can't "force" you to do anything. If you don't like it then speak up. If they're immovable then find a job somewhere else.

Comment: "`I have ... tasks to complete as a Freelancer too`" - can you take freelancing full-time?

Comment: What country are you in? In many countries you could just tell them that anything over 8h of work you can do, but will bill them as freelancer if it won't be official overtime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> We are not paid overtime here. 10 A.M to 7.30 P.M is our working time, means 9 hours 30 minutes. [...]

Several red flags I see, however to answer your actual question...

*If your working hours are already indicated, ending at 7:30pm, then by all means you are in full rights to leave after the end time or after you fulfill those 9.5 hours.*

Now about the red flags. Doing overtime without payment is surely not beneficial to you, and being "forced" to stay doesn't seem to be like the best work environment. To worsen things, you indicate you have already brought this to the manager's attention, and no action has been taken...

... Given all these things, it seems that **it would be wise of you to update your CV and start seeking a job elsewhere** (somewhere that at least has payed overtime, for your sake), as you will only end up burnout and continue to be exploited.

Answer (score 5):

**Ah the good 'ol days of forced labour and slavery...**

**A*RE GONE!***

...in western countries legally anyways

Your options are:
(chose any combination you like)

- find another job and quit
- Simply leave when your contractual time is over
  1)they can't physically prevent you from leaving
  (*that pesky unlawful imprisonment thing*)
  -they might terminate your contract out of spite though
  2) legally you have the law on your side(again,depending on country)
- Tell them the deadline is too short
- let them know you have other, private  obligations (helps if you have a family, small children etc.)
- Involve a union or employment lawyer
- Flat out tell them you're willing to do overtime if a delivery is up but you won't stay every day way over your contractual hours
- Whistleblow or leave an anonymous tip at the controlling governmental body

About that time thing, keep in mind that your breaks are quite often not included in your time (depending on contract / law in locale)

So 9 hours at work including a lunchbreak and two smaller breaks count pretty much as an 8 hour workday...

**Read your contract to be certain.**

...Oh and if you're held against your will, involve authorities immediately.

-> call the POLICE

Comment: A really outstanding answer.  It's a shame when *other contributors* make it more complicated than this.

Comment: @Fattie cheers mate! Rock on!

Answer (score 2):

Okay... Standard warning here.  Update your resume and float it.

Once you start to get interviews, pushback **HARD**

Don't mention that you've been on interviews or have offers (if any).

But, when you do, you can go in and negotiate from a position of strength.  At that time, make your desires known.  You don't want to deliver an ultimatum, but you want to state clearly that.

1. You are not satisfied with the hours
2. You are not satisfied with the pay
3. You expect them to address this immediately, and give them a timeframe.

If they don't at that point address it, they never will, and you will know it's time to move on.

If they do, then you can stay at your job with the new pay and/or hours.

Comment: Having "interviews" isn't really much leverage to push back tho...

Comment: @solarflare if you get the interviews, you'll have an offer.

Comment: I dont know about you but I've flunked more interviews than I've gotten offers.

Comment: Just a warning: you don't want to negotiate shorter hours compared to the rest of your coworkers.  Because every coworker you have is going to be working 9+ hours and see you leave after 8 each day, and your manager is going to see you as the troublesome one that doesn't "put in a full day."  If the hours are a deal-killer, it's better to just flat leave - not negotiate them.

Comment: @solarflare My hit rate is 1 offer per 3 interviews, the standard is 1 per 10, but I am **VERY** experienced and taught classes on it.  Still, get the interviews, and you'll be able to leave.

Comment: @Kevin you still need to be getting those interviews if you want to leave.

Comment: @RichardU - I'm speaking specifically about the part where you advise negotiating with the current employer for much shorter hours.  I'm saying *that* part of your advice is wrong.  Because if everyone else is working 10 hours and you're working 8... that's not a situation that's tenable in the long term.  Coworkers and boss will be resentful, with a clearly visible reminder of it every day.  If the hours are a killer, negotiating a different set of hours than everyone else is a bad idea.  Just move on to a different place.

Comment: @RichardU I usually choke at technical questions at interviews due to nerves.  For me its more like 1/8.

Comment: @Kevin there's plenty of rooms for other answers.  Comments are not for debate.

Answer (score 1):

**Figure out how long it's personally optimal to stay.**

I had a job at a company that, while not quite as bad as yours, was pretty terrible.  Our boss printed out charts every monday with the hours everyone had worked the week before.  If you were the person who worked the least, you'd get chewed out.  Sure, you put in hours of unpaid overtime, but you didn't put in *as many* hours as the others.  So you'd get reamed a bit - to encourage you to *not* be the person who put in the least.

I worked there for ~18 months, and I wouldn't change anything looking back.  I improved my SQL skills *substantially*, going from "I can generally write simple Select statements" to "Bordering on full-fledged DBA".  I got exposure to some better programming styles as well as experience being a PM for a project I was in charge of.

You *are* probably going to want to move on to another job - you'll probably get burnt out staying where you are for too long.  But keep an eye on when it'll be *optimal* for you to leave.  If you're developing valuable skills/abilities, it might be worth it to suck things up for a little while, until the amount you're learning/improving is outweighed by the stress of the job.  If you're not getting much value out of the job right now?  You should probably move on as soon as you can.

Comment: Wish we could add that company to "the list"

Comment: Yeah.  What was *really* sad, and was the thing that ultimately convinced me to leave was... it seemed everyone working there was either single, divorced, in marriage counselling, or relatively new to the company.  None of the people there more than 5 years had a happy home life.  Everyone trudged out of the building at the end of the day, unhappy and miserable... and it didn't take a genius to realize that the reason their home lives were bad was because they were taking that moodiness home with them.

Comment: @Kevin exactly man, such work life balance also affects relations with family and friends.

Answer (score 1):

This is just building off other answers (by the way, Welcome!).

Personally, I would say: If your other obligations are family or scheduled items or necessary for your physical or mental health; do not stay at work.  Ensure long before the day is over that these prior engagements are known to your supervisor and coworker in advance.

If this is "once, twice, or thrice," and does nothing other than inconvenience you, then let them know.  I suspect you are in a country where making demands or reaching out to HR are not options, so play it cool.  **Make known your schedule in advance, so you have at least the opportunity to say you were planning on not staying after 7:30** and it was made clear earlier.